# Play AudioStream (RTP, HTTP) on Android

Tags: android, http, audio, stream, rtp

I'm using Android MediaPlayer to play a stream on my device but I get an error upon playing a stream.

I'm using VLC on my PC to stream Audio to my device. With the Android version of the VLC I am able to play the sound on my device, so my streaming is OK.

Here's a my code:

```
try {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource("http://192.168.3.111:8080/xx");
    //player.setSurface(null);
    //player.prepare();
    player.prepareAsync();
    //player.start();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
    });

    player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e("RTP", "ERROR: " + what + "  " + extra);
            return false;
        }
    });

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("RTP", e.getMessage());
}
```

Every time I get the following error:
error (1, -2147483648)

I tried RTP, RTSP, HTTP and always same result.

Update1: Is it a codec problem? I stream mp3 without any transcoding.

Comment: It seems like a codec problem..
While I am able to stream rtsp (aud/vid) from ffmpeg to ffmpeg as well as vlc to ffmpeg - but unable to do the same with android mediaplayer/videoview
problem is the error description is not giving any hint.

Comment: have you resolve it yet? i need the solution too...

Comment: no there was no solution!

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue ? I'm facing to the same problem